# Sharepoint 2013 - Result Type Priority

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, resulttype

I successfully managed to create two custom result types with two custom display templates.

I configured the result types in the way, that if the titel of the result item contains "String 1" it uses *Item_Case1* and if the title contains "String 2" it uses *Item_Case2*.

Now I tried to play around with the priorites.
If the title is "**String 1** blablabla **String 2**" I want it to use "Item_Case1".

```
A little schematic how I want it to be:
(SearchTerm --> Display Template)

 - "String 1 bla bla"         --> "Item_Case1"
 - "String 2 bla bla"         --> "Item_Case2"
 - "String 1 blabla String 2" --> "Item_Case1"
```

According to [this site](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/10/13/sharepoint-2013-the-concept-of-result-types-in-search/) the priority which display template will be used is defined by the standing in the list of result types.

But no matter what I tried, it wouldn't work. The only (ugly) workaround I found was to deactivate the templates by altering the searchTerm from "String 1" to "String 1bla" first and then activate them in the order I needed them.

So, is this a known bug or did I do something wrong?